# where does sem_open shared memory on osx

Tags: ios, macos, shared-memory, semaphore

I am currently porting a C lib for iOS, and need to change original sem_init() to sem_open() because
iOS not support sem_init()

I have seen some discussions telling that sem_open() will open a shared memory file in system, now I want to check if sem_open() a semaphore successfully by verifying the shared memory file.

Have tried to find in /dev/shm, but there is no shm directory, but sem_open not returns "SEM_FAILED", so where does the shared memory file go?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page of `sem_open()` on OS X:

> There is no visible entry in the file system for the created object in
>   this implementation.